# Xcode 9 and Xcode server: user is not logged in

Tags: xcode-server

Before High Sierra and Xcode9, xcode server was managed from server.app and was working fine. Since updating to High Sierra and Xcode9, I have been having trouble with xcode server. Integrations are pending because the bot user is not logged in.
[image]
However, when I check Xcode bot tab, the bot user is marked as logged in.

[image]

What I already tried:

1. Reinstalled xcode and created a new bot account.
2. Use admin user for integrations
3. Disabled screen saver and screen locker

Workarround: Log out bot profile and then log in again.

Comment: Same problem here, only that your workaround does not help. Did you find a real solution by now?

Comment: Toggling the switch in the top right from ON to OFF and then back to ON again made it work for me - until it stopped again a little later, where I had to toggle it off and on again. :-I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had this issue and it turns out that (maybe due to the many Xcode upgrades since 2016) the cross-bot Xcode Server setup must have become corrupted. Once we wiped the entire Xcode Server and re-created the bot manually, with the exact same configuration as before, everything worked out fine.

To wipe, we used `sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset` which stops the daemons and purges `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer`. See https://honzadvorsky.com/articles/2015-05-04-under-the-hood-of-xcode-server/ for further reference.